# How to detect if view-source is valid for Location Object in the current browser?

Tags: javascript

There are a Javascript (or jQuery) method or property, that can detect if a `window.location` assign command,

```
window.location.assign("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

will be used to show the source-code of the page?  That is, if the command,

```
window.location.assign("view-source:http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

works with the client's browser.

---

Related questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/24894999/287948
- ...

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to rely on the browser to do it instead of just serving the page with a `Content-type: text/plain` header?

Comment: Yes, view-source (see ex. Chrome browser) will render and show pretty view. In particular to show URLs of `Content-type: text/xml` pages, because show the tree.